# How to get rid of prompt line in IDLE IDE 3.10?

Tags: python, python-idle

There's a line in IDLE IDE in 3.10 version on Windows, which did not exist in prior versions.
Is there a way to get rid of it?

I have tried changing themes but there still doesn't seem to be any way to get rid of it.

[image: Image of IDLE IDE 3.10 with the line]

For reference:

[image: IDLE IDE 3.7]

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Comment: @KellyBundy It's purely personal preference and I find it quite distracting.

Comment: I suspect you'll quickly get used to it. At least I did.

Comment: [Discussion about the change](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82084), in case you're interested.

Comment: It's just that I'd like to share what I write on IDLE on twitter and the line kind of gets in the way . While I'm aware services like carbon.sh exist, I'd like to go for a minimalist approach such as this, or resort to IPython on Powershell or cmd, which I'm not really a fan of .

Comment: How does it "get in the way"?

Comment: It doesn't look good is what I'm trying to say

Comment: So you're tweeting screenshots? Maybe tweet text instead, which also has the advantage of letting people copy&paste the code? (I don't use Twitter and I don't know what code you tweet, so I can't tell whether that would work for you.)

Comment: @Rusty were you able to hide the sidebar?

Comment: @mapperx nah, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this bothers a few people and will do something sometime when I can.  A problem is that the visual details of widgets depend on at least the OS and that appearance-only patches have to be tested by people, not code, and need testing on at least 1 Windows, Linux, and Mac system.

I just tried out Classic Dark and it has an annoying white line once applied, though not in the preview.  I use a custom dark them with dark blue text background and light blue sidebar background (204, 204, 255 in the Windows color chooser) and I don't see any white or black line.  I think there may be lines that blend into the light and dark blues.  (The sidebar color is called 'line number' because the latter were added a few years ago.)

For a light theme, a light gray sidebar, (222,222,222) has much the same effect for me and I like it much better than with the white sidebar background.

Comment: Please, and thanks! Your light theme suggestion is a lot more bearable. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Terry were you able to make a fix as you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Not yet.  Am thinking about a bigger change.